# Console Command Utility for progress?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

A customer has a progress database and I need to be able to connect using a command line client. Does such a thing exist? Ive seen on the server you can launch proenv and run sqlexp, and I'd like to be able to do similar from a dev machine to the remote DB.

Answer (score 4):

Any dev machine with Progress installed will have PROENV available.

For SQL access "sqlexp" will work just as you have already used it. If you need 4GL access you can use "pro" (single user) or "mpro" (multi-user). Remote access is always going to be multi-user.

You probably used a SQLEXP command similar to this:

```
proenv> sqlexp -db dbName -H hostName -S servicePort -user userName -password passWord -infile something.sql
```

The equivalent for MPRO would be:

```
proenv> mpro  -db dbName -H hostName -S servicePort -U userName -P passWord -p something.p
```

In both cases if you omit the program to run (something.*) parameter you will be greeted by a prompt. SQLEXP is more of a command line, MPRO is an "editor" with a menu system at the top but you can also just type 4GL statements and execute them directly with the "GO" key (F2 for Windows, F1 for Unix, alternatively ^X for either platform).

It is common (although a bad idea) in older applications to permit "blank" userid access for 4GL clients so you may be able to succeed in connecting by omitting the -U and -P. If you get a dialog asking for username and password try entering nothing or exiting the dialog with F4 (or ^E). That might work if you have no credentials and such access is allowed.

The licensing of the machine that you are connecting from may impact what you can do with that connection. There is also always a utility called "showcfg" which will show you a list of the configured licenses.

That's all just basic connectivity. We might have more to say if we know what it is that you want to do once you are connected.